# Getting Error(NZEC) when trying to compile Java file

Tags: java

I am getting an error(NZEC) while compiling the following programme.
I am unable to figure out the error. Seems like I have done nothing wrong.

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;

class mixture{
public static void main(String args[]) {
    Scanner x=new Scanner(System.in);
    int n;
    n=x.nextInt();
    int a[]=new int[n];

    for(int i=0;i<n;i++) {
        a[i]=x.nextInt();
    }
    Arrays.sort(a);
    System.out.println(a[0]*a[1]);  
}
}
```

The error I am getting is :

```
 Main.java:4: error: class mixture is public, should be declared in a file 
named mixture.java
public class mixture {
   ^
1 error
```

Comment: You should always at least try compiling and running your code locally (not on some web site) before asking a question.  Java has at least 2 decent free IDEs (IDEA Community edition and Eclipse).  Note that I don't see any _compilation_ errors, so you must be getting a RuntimeException which you should specify.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Calculate Hash or Checksum for a table in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1560306/calculate-hash-or-checksum-for-a-table-in-sql-server)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [runtime error (NZEC) Java SPOJ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22160814/runtime-error-nzec-java-spoj)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Java you always need to use the class name as the file name.

So if your class is called `mixture`, then you need to save the file under the name `mixture.java`. (Note that it is also convention in Java to make class names upper case, so you should call it `Mixture`).

Obviously, your file is named `Main.java` (so says your error message). If you want to keep the file name, you need to rename your class to `Main` instead.

(Note that if you are working online on some web site - you don't state this, but a commenter mentioned something like that - then maybe the website has the convention that you need to call your class `Main` and you cannot change that...)